# Combining React Final Form Array and Final Form Calculate

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form, react-final-form-arrays

I am having a really hard time accessing the objects within the field array for a calculated field price * quantity = total . Have tried a bunch of regex for the decorated field including `field: /invoiceItems\[\d+\]/ ,` to access and the solution from this PR (https://github.com/final-form/final-form-calculate/pull/21/commits/dab00f8125079fed402712a4b0ed71663be0ba14)

In the PR I cant access the index. What is the best way to do a calculation with final form calculate and arrays? I have tried this in Formik as well but ran into the same issue.

Code

Form:

```
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
          decorators={[calculator]}
          mutators={{
            ...arrayMutators,
          }}
          initialValues={{
            companyName: "",
            companyAddress: "",
            companyCity: "",
            companyState: "",
            companyZip: "",
            invoiceNumber: shortid.generate(),
            invoicePaymentStatus: "",
            invoiceStatus: "",
            invoiceItems: [

            ],
            invoiceDate: new Date(),
            invoiceDueDate: new Date(
              new Date().getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
            ),
            clientFname: "",
            clientLname: "",
            billingAddress: "",
            billingCity: "",
            billingState: "",
            billingZip: "",
            propertyAddress: "",
            propertyCity: "",
            propertyState: "",
            propertyZip: "",
            invoiceTotal: "",
            tax: "",
          }}
          render={({
            handleSubmit,
            reset,
            submitting,
            pristine,
            values,
            form: {
              mutators: { push, pop },
            },
          }) => (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
```

Field Array:

```
                            type="button"
                            onClick={() => push("invoiceItems", undefined)}
                          >
                            Add Line Item
                          </button>
                          <FieldArray name="invoiceItems">
                            {({ fields }) =>
                              fields.map((item, index) => (
                                <div key={item}>
                                  <Field
                                    name={`${item}.description`}
                                    component={TextField}
                                    placeholder="Description"
                                  />
                                  <Field
                                    name={`${item}.price`}
                                    component={TextField}
                                    placeholder="Price"
                                  />
                                  <Field
                                    name={`${item}.quantity`}
                                    component={TextField}
                                    placeholder="Quantity"
                                  />
                                  <Field
                                    name={`${item}.total`}
                                    component={TextField}
                                    placeholder="Total"
                                  />
                                  <span
                                    onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
                                    style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                                  >
                                    ❌
                                  </span>
                                </div>
                              ))
                            }
                          </FieldArray>
```

Here is some of the Decorator I have tried. (Its a disaster with so many different attempts & ignore the math as we were just trying to get it to work)

```
    { 
      field: /invoiceItems\[\d+\]/ ,
      updates: {(name, index, value) => {
        [`invoiceItems[${index}].total`]: (_ignored, values) =>  2 
        //invoiceItems.total: (price, allValues) => price * 2
      }
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Did end up fixing it based on this: [How do I combine `final-form-calculate` with `final-form-array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714512/how-do-i-combine-final-form-calculate-with-final-form-array)

Here is the finished code:

```
const calculator = createDecorator(
  {
    field: /invoiceItems\[\d+\]\.price/,
    updates: (value, name, allValues) => {
      const totalField = name.replace(".price", ".total");
      const quantityField = name.replace(".price", ".quantity");
      return {
        [totalField]: parseInt(value) * parseInt(getIn(allValues, quantityField)),
      };
    },
  },
  {
    field: /invoiceItems\[\d+\]\.quantity/,
    updates: (value, name, allValues) => {
      const totalField = name.replace(".quantity", ".total");
      const priceField = name.replace(".quantity", ".price");
      return {
        [totalField]: parseInt(value) * parseInt(getIn(allValues, priceField)),
      };
    },
  }
);
```